# Spring integration flow fails on performance testing with jmeter

Tags: spring-integration

My integration flow works fine normally. but when I tried to do a performance test on the integration flow using JMeter, I am getting the following error.

> "2021-04-01 15:44:48.538  WARN 22636 --- [ XNIO-1 task-41]
> cMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel : Reply message received but
> the receiving thread has already received a reply: GenericMessage"

I have an inbound gateway that receives the request and an outbound gateway to fetch results from another server. I handled exceptions at the outbound gateway by advice chain (ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice).  Can anyone help me? Can anyone tell me what causes this issue?

Note:  if I use 5 threads to test then the flow works fine. But if I increase the thread count on JMeter then the number of failed requests also increases.

Comment: This probably means you have a thread-safety problem in your application because multiple replies are being received by the gateway for the same request. Examine all your code for thread safety.

Comment: We can't tell anything without seeing your code.